# Ajax reCaptcha 2.0 Verify

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, recaptcha

I have a form that submits via Ajax. I want to implement Google's Recaptcha 2.0 on this form. My ajax is posting to a PHP script. Everyone works great until I try to implement captcha.

I just want to know how to verify in my ajax that the recaptcha was checked.

My code is below:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
    <form role="form" id="contactForm">
    <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label for="name" class="h4">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" required data-error="Please enter your name">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label for="email" class="h4">Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" required data-error="Please enter your email">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message" class="h4 ">Message</label>
            <textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Enter your message" required data-error="Please enter your message"></textarea>
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" id="captcha" data-sitekey="#mySiteKey#" data-error="Please prove your human"></div>
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="form-submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right">Submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function submitForm(){
// Initiate Variables With Form Content
var name = $("#name").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var message = $("#message").val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "includes/core/class.contact2.php",
    data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message,
    success : function(text){
        if (text == "success"){
            formSuccess();
        } else {
            formError();
            submitMSG(false,text);
        }
    }
});
```

}

PHP

```
//set error message
$errorMSG = "";
//check if fields are filled in
if(empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $errorMSG = "Name is required";
}   else {
    $name = $db->quote($_POST['name']);
}
if(empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $errorMSG = "Email is missing";
} else {
    $email = $db->quote($_POST['email']);
}
if(empty($_POST['message'])) {
    $errorMSG = "Message is missing";
} else {
    $message = $db->quote($_POST['message']);
}

//insert result
$result = $db->query("INSERT into requests (name,email,message) VALUES (". $name ."," . $email . "," . $message . ")");
```

Comment: What goes wrong?  What part of the code fails?

Comment: @ryanyuyu I just want to know how to verify in my ajax that the recaptcha was checked

Comment: submitter specified his question in the comments

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to know how to verify in my ajax that the recaptcha was checked

You have to know how [reCaptcha works](https://webscraping.pro/no-captcha-recaptcha-challenge/). 
After user clicks reCaptcha and google server returns result, google api on client side creates a new hidden form field with returned encoded value (that contains info if test is passed or not), [docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify).
So you add this field value into your submission procedure:

```
function submitForm(){
// Initiate Variables With Form Content
var name = $("#name").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var message = $("#message").val();
var g_captcha_response = $("#g-recaptcha-response").val();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "includes/core/class.contact2.php",
data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message, "&resp=" + $("#g-recaptcha-response").val(),
success : function(text){
    if (text == "success"){
        formSuccess();
    } else {
        formError();
        submitMSG(false,text);
      }
   }
});
```

And after that you need to verify this response (server side) using *secret key*:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$url='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
$response=$_POST['resp'];
$secret = "[secter_key]"; 
$params = array('secret'=> $secret, 'response'=> $response);
$json=file_get_contents( $url  . '?secret=' . $secret . '&response=' .    $response);
echo $json;
```

Comment: I am just learning Ajax and how it works. I used this tutorial on how to implement it into my form. When I made your changes above, it stopped the script from validating the form on submit - https://github.com/tutsplus/building-a-bootstrap-contact-form-using-php-and-ajax

Comment: @Jmostaind55, were you able to fetch `g-recaptcha-response` value?

Comment: No I was not able to get this to work. I am using the code from the github in the above comment.